# What software to use to make Python-based website using MSSQL

Tags: python, sql-server

I need to build a simple web page using Python with the data fetched from MSSQL (Unfortunately, I cannot use MySQL and other easy awesome DBs). I tried with installing Django but encountered with endless problem with sqlserver module, tried in both Windows and Ubuntu. I though about using a light framework like web.py but I found that it does not support MSSQL.

What software should I use to build the web page? Do I need to use a framework? If not, how best I can put the HTML code while running it on a server?

I am searching for a simple solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which sql module did you try? If the module you tried was django-mmsql and you encountered issues,  an alternative is [django-pymssql](https://github.com/aaugustin/django-pymssql) on github. This is supposed to work on non-Windows systems.

If you want to give a different framework a try,  web2py has a built in database abstraction layer supporting MSSQL. You can check out web2py's database features [here](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer) to see if it meets your requirements.